# Maximizing a function of two variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the simple function:

$\qquad f(x,a)=a\,x−ln(x/100)$

with the constraints: $0.1 < a < 1$ and $0.1 < x < 10$

I want find the minimum of $f(x,\,a)$, assuming that the variable $a$ can take the worst value.

When I evaluated the following code

```
f[x_, a_] := a*x - Log[x/100];
Minimize[{f[x, a], 0.1 < x < 10, 0.1 < a < 1}, x]  
Maximize[{%, 0.1 < x < 10, 0.1 < a < 1}, a]
```

I got

> ```
> Maximize[
>   {Minimize[{a x - Log[x/100], 0.1 < x < 10, 0.1 < a < 1}, x],
>   0.1 < x < 10, 0.1 < a < 1}, a]
> ```

Any suggestions? -_-

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, a_] := a*x - Log[x/100];
```

The minimum in the region is

```
min1 = Minimize[{f[x, a], 0.1 < x < 10, 0.1 < a < 1}, {a, x}]

(* {3.30259, {a -> 0.1, x -> 10.}} *)
```

The minimum for the worst case value of `a` is

```
min2 = Minimize[{f[x, a], 0.1 < x < 10, a == 1}, {a, x}]

(* {5.60517, {a -> 1., x -> 1.}} *)

ContourPlot[f[x, a], {x, 0.1, 10}, {a, 0.1, 1},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, a}),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotLabel -> Style[f[x, a], 14, Bold], Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Green, Tooltip[Point[{x, a}], f[x, a]] /. min1[[2]],
   Red,
   Tooltip[Point[{x, a}], f[x, a]] /. min2[[2]]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, a], {x, 0.1, 10}, {a, 0.1, 1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, a, f})],
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Green, Point[{x, a, f[x, a]} /. min1[[2]]],
   Red,
   Point[{x, a, f[x, a]} /. min2[[2]]]}],
 PlotLabel -> Style[f[x, a], 14, Bold],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answear, but I wanna know in general why my minimization problem doesn't work. This function is so simple that  you see that a =1 is the worst case but with more complicated function is not possible that approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at that time `Minimize` only work for concrete number.

```
Clear["`*"];
f[x_, a_] := a*x - Log[x/100];
Table[Minimize[{f[x, a], 1/10 < x < 10 }, x], {a, 1/10, 1, 1/20}]
```

So we have to use `D`.

Since `D[f[x,a],{x,2}]=1/x^2>0` we can `Solve` `D[f[x,a],x]==0` to find the minimize.

```
D[f[x,a],{x,2}]
(* 1/x^2 *)

Solve[D[f[x, a], x] == 0, x]
(*{{x -> 1/a}}*)

f[x,a]/.%
(* {1 - Log[1/(100 a)]} *)
```

So the function `f[x,a]` get it's minimize at `x=1/a` and the  minimize value is

`1 - Log[1/(100 a)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here I present a direct solution of this "min-min-Problem"

First calculate the minimum depending of a;

```
min[a_?NumericQ] := {#[[1]], x /. #[[2]]} & [NMinimize[{a*x - Log[x/100], 0.1 < x < 10  }, {x }]]
```

Second calculate the "worst" `a`

```
aworst = a /. NMinimize[{min[a][[1]], 0.1 < a < 1}, a][[2]]
(* 0.1 *)
```

result

```
Plot[ {min[a][[1]], min[a][[2]]} , {a, .1, 1},PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red} ,   PlotLabels -> {"min[a]", "x[a]"},GridLines -> {{{aworst, {Thickness[.02],Darker[Green]} }}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. We take the same step but with your implementation works fine!  :)